# How do I create a custom report in Google Analytics of just users that have viewed a product detail page?

Tags: reporting, advanced-segments

I have a Segment which identifies Users who view at least 1 Product Detail Page during their session.

I'm trying to create a quick shortcut to a comprehensive view of these Users behaviours during their whole session - the ideal is a Custom Report. I've tried a number of things:

1. **Created a Custom Report - Problem**: It does not retain the Segment.
2. **Created a Saved Report with the Segment assigned - Problem**: I cannot edit this report to add extra Tabs in the way I can with Custom Reports.
3. **Attempted to create a Custom Report using filters instead of a Segment - Problem**: The filters only seem to allow for AND. So while I can create a Custom Report which includes the Product pages - it *only* includes the product pages, not all the pages viewed during the session.

The URL is something like this: `/product-category/product`

I'm now all out of ideas, and hoping someone will be able to light my way.

Comment: What do you want in the extra tabs?

Comment: Well I haven't finalised it yet, but I may want a tab dealing with each of the following: landing/exit pages, source/medium, devices, new v returning.

Comment: Don't the default set of reports do all that?  All you have to do to see them is apply the segment.

Comment: The key phrase was 'quick shortcut'. A Custom Report is a way of nesting a set of reports - which allow a comprehensive overview to be formed in double-quick time. No navigating through submenus and you can group metrics together differently to the default reports.